# How to maintain insert ordering for one-to-many relationship in Django

Tags: django, django-orm

How to maintain insert ordering with one-to-many Django mapping, for eg:
Say we have,

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = Model.CharField(max_length=50)

class Subject(models.Model):
    sub_name = Model.CharField(max_length=50)
    person = Model.ForeignKey('Person')

def insert_data():
    person = Person.objects.create(name='Deepan')
    Subject(name='Eng', person=person).save()
    Subject(name='Sci', person=person).save()

Subject.objects.filter(person=person) # is there a way to make this to always return the subjects in the inserted order, i.e Eng, Sci instead of Sci, Eng
```

This is handled using list types in hibernate/grails

Answer (score 4):

Define the ordering using meta info:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    sub_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person')
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['time'] #or ['-time'] according to the ordering you require
```

This will save the creation datetime in the time field and hence the results will be ordered according to addition time.

btw (if there are some other reasons) from your models it seems there will be many `Persons` and many `Subjects` so I suggest using [many to many fields](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships). This will map multiple users to multiple subjects and symmetrically back. You may even use the [`through`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) option to store more details (time etc for sorting, even marks/percentage for storing records if you require to do that) per `Person`-`Subject` mapping.

Comment: We are not looking for a sort order, but insertion order

Comment: That's exactly what I suggested. See notes on proxy models.

Comment: you are correct @drow, proxy class will prevent redundant sorting operations.

Comment: I know this is a really old question.. but I have the same problem but I would like to manually modify the order, like managing a list. Is that possible?ej, I have order [a,b,c] as it was inserted and I want to change manually the order to [a,c,b]

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a meta class to always sort it and use a date time field with the auto_now option set to True.
I recommend using a proxy class for the sorting. Sorting is an expensive operation.
See [this link](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/ordering/) for more details on sorting and [this link](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) on proxy models.

Comment: This way of maintaining order with a date time field, make it difficult to change the ordering later from the code. Frameworks like hibernate maintains a separate order column in the database and a ordered collection like list in the java code

Comment: @Deepan S: But this is not Hibernate and this is how things work. You already have two answers that suggest that which makes me think that I'm probably right here.

Comment: Also, if you use a proxy model, you wouldn't have to use the sorted model if you want some other sorting done.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['id']
```

And no additional fields required. Django model always has 'id' field.

Comment: #nide it is not always necessary that the autogenerated id field is stored in correct order. For eg: In case of google app engine (google datastore) the `auto generated fields` get random ids. So to be safe I think a time based field to monitor this should be a good idea.

Comment: What is reason for generating random ids in google datastore?

Comment: well I don't know exactly, but I see this happening so suggested. Not sure if it happens with any relation databases. But to be completely sure I still suggest use of time field.

Comment: Another case where the ids would not be sequential is if the children are created in a separate process. A child insterted first was not necessarily crested first.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for exactly the same and to `order_with_respecto_to` works:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        order_with_respect_to = 'game'
```

You can see the original order as they where inserted and you can modify it if you want. Also you can get the next register in sequence

```
>>> from prueba.models import Game,Task
>>> a=Game.objects.get(id=1)
>>> a.get_task_order()
<QuerySet [1, 2, 3]>
>>> a.set_task_order([3,2,1])
>>> a.get_task_order()
<QuerySet [3, 2, 1]>
>>> t=Task.objects.get(id=2)
>>> t.get_next_in_order()
<Task: task1>
>>> t=Task.objects.get(id=3)
>>> t.get_next_in_order()
<Task: task2>
```

Here is the documentation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#order-with-respect-to